# How to use the Angular 6 Pipe syntax correctly

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm currently following this tutorial to learn how to build an angular client on top of a Spring Boot web service: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/12/04/basic-crud-angular-and-spring-boot

The problem I've run into is within the following code snippet:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class GiphyService {

    // Public beta key: https://github.com/Giphy/GiphyAPI#public-beta-key
    giphyApi = '//api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC&limit=1&q=';

    constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    }

    get(searchTerm) {
        const apiLink = this.giphyApi + searchTerm;
        return this.http.get(apiLink).map((response: any) => {
            if (response.data.length > 0) {
                return response.data[0].images.original.url;
            } else {
                return 'https://media.giphy.com/media/YaOxRsmrv9IeA/giphy.gif'; // dancing cat for 404
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I've done extensive research and bled over the course of the past 24 hours, and here's what I've come to so far. The import is outdated in the newer version of angular, so I've changed the import to:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'
```

Also, it would seem that the .map operator is now deprecated, and apparently you need to use the pipe syntax. My issue is that I've tried to make use of it but I just can't seem to figure it out. The following throws a syntax error:

```
get(searchTerm) {
    const apiLink = this.giphyApi + searchTerm;
    return this.http.get(apiLink)
        .pipe(
            map((response: any) => {
                if (response.data.length > 0) {
                    return response.data[0].images.original.url;
                } else {
                    return 'https://media.giphy.com/media/YaOxRsmrv9IeA/giphy.gif'; // dancing cat for 404
                }
            });
        )
}
```

I'm probably staring into a wall of text considering that I've been learning so much this past week, so forgive me in advance if I'm missing something simple.

Comment: It throws what error?

Comment: Thank you for this comment, it made me look at the code again. Turns out it was expecting the ")" to be in front of the semicolon and not after it. It was just me being silly again, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

So it turns out that I was being as silly as I thought. I tried to use the closing bracket after the semicolon. Please see the below updated function:

```
get(searchTerm) {
    const apiLink = this.giphyApi + searchTerm;
    return this.http.get(apiLink)
        .pipe(
            map((response: any) => {
                if (response.data.length > 0) {
                    return response.data[0].images.original.url;
                } else {
                    return 'https://media.giphy.com/media/YaOxRsmrv9IeA/giphy.gif'; // dancing cat for 404
                }
            })); //The closing bracket for pipe needs to be here
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the TypeScript compiler throw an error? I mean that code shouldn't even compile.